# Reading .txt file into 2-D array

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, file-io

I am trying to read in a "map" into my program.  it's a list of 100 numbers, I want it to be a 10 x 10 array.  I'm trying to use a void function to read the file.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

const int rows = 10, columns = 10, inaccessible = 0, start = 1, victory = 2;
typedef unsigned int world[rows][columns];

void loadWorld (world map[rows][columns]);

int main()
{
    cout << "Welcome to my game!  Get to the bottom of the volcano to win." << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
            cout << world[i][j];
    }


    return 0;
}

void loadWorld (world map[rows][columns])
{
    ifstream inData;

    inData.open("world.txt");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To read it in, do the opposite of what you do with `cout`:

```
inData >> map[i][j];
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a naive example. The output is formatted.

```
#include <iostream>

#define Rows 3
#define Cols 2

int main()
{
    int Matrix[Rows][Cols];

    //Input
    for(int i = 0; i < Cols; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < Rows; j++)
            std::cin >> Matrix[j][i];

    //Output
    for(int i = 0; i < Cols; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < Rows; j++)
            std::cout << Matrix[j][i] << "\t";
        std::cout << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Visual C++ is telling me that type name is not allowed on my unsigned int world.  Did I declare the type wrong?

Comment: If you are compiling the first code you posted... then maybe you are trying with stc::cout << world[][] instead of declaring word MYWORLD[][] previously after doing it you can use MYWORLD... Remember "world" is typedef and it's not a variable